# Numpad выключен при включенном numlock

Tags: windows, windows-10

Я пытался вводить альткоды, но ничего не получалось. Начал разбираться, выяснилось что криво работает нумлок. У меня в ноутбуке нумпад находится на сенсорной панели, и чтобы на нем что-то набрать нужно удерживать палец в углу панели, иначе он не появится. Проблема в том, что когда нумпад включен, нумлок тоже включен, а альткоды работают только при выключенном нумлоке. Что нужно делать чтобы сменить значение нумлока?

Comment: на Linux этим занимается [xmodmap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9))

Comment: @DiD я вроде прилепил тег виндовс 10

Comment: xmodmap я посмотрел, оно мне не поможет